# Cell color of table in Reportlab Library using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, reportlab

I am writing a pdf with reportlab library.

I added code for this

```
text = Paragraph(str(df['accountName'][0]),
              styles['Justify'])
data= [['ACCOUNT'],
       [text],
       ]
f = Table(data)
f.setStyle(TableStyle([
   ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (0, -1), colors.red)
   ]))
f.wrapOn(pdf, 200, 50)
f.drawOn(pdf, 210, 632)
```

So I am getting this output:

[image]

But actually I want **General** word in red color not account! How can I fix this?

Comment: `f.setStyle(TableStyle([
   ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 1), (0, -1), colors.red)` ?

Answer (score 0):

ReportLab [TableStyle Commands](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A325%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Fit%22%7D%5D)

> The first element of each command is its identifier, the second and third arguments determine the cell coordinates of the box of cells which are affected with negative coordinates counting backwards from the limit values as in Python indexing. The coordinates are given as (column, row) which follows the spreadsheet 'A1' model, but not the more natural (for mathematicians) 'RC' ordering. The top left cell is (0, 0) the bottom right is (-1, -1).

```
f.setStyle(TableStyle([
    ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 1), (0, -1), colors.red)
]))
```

If there are rows following then you will need to `(0, 1), (0, 1)` which will target a single row instead of `(0, 1), (0, -1)` which will select rows starting at index 1 all the way to the last row.

Comment: Both are not working, you are absolutely right this is suppose to be the right answer but i don't know why it is not showing any output now both lines are getting black